# deleting white space at the end of for loop output in php

Tags: php

can any body help me how I can delete the white space at the end of the output.
This might be easy question but to be honest it took me more than 45 minutes and still nothing. **Assignment**

Write a PHP script that prints the numbers from the number inputted on form to zero. The numbers should be separated with a single space but the last number, zero, should not have a space after it. If the user inputs a number smaller than zero, print “The number should be at least zero!” The used form looks like this:

Luku:

Example output

5 4 3 2 1 0

**my code:**

```
     <?php
 $number=$_GET["number"]; 


if ($number < 0){

  echo "The number should be at least zero!";

} else {


for($i=$number; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
{
echo $i." ";

}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [trim()](http://pk1.php.net/trim)

```
<?php
   $number=$_GET["number"]; 
   if ($number < 0){
      echo "The number should be at least zero!";
   } else {
      $num = '';
      for($i=$number; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
      {
         $num .= $i." ";
      }
      echo trim($num);
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo implode(" ",range($number,0));
```

[Magic](http://php.net/range) and [trickery](http://php.net/implode) ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rtrim](https://www.php.net/rtrim) instead of `trim` to delete white spaces at the end of the string:

```
<?php
$number=$_GET["number"]; 
if ($number < 0){
  echo "The number should be at least zero!";
} else {
    for($i=$number; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
    {
        $num .= $i." ";
    }
}
$num = rtrim($num);
?>
```

Comment: Please explain how OP would use `rtrim` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if-statement:

```
<?php
    $number=$_GET["number"]; 
    if ($number < 0) {
        echo "The number should be at least zero!";
    } else {
        for($i=$number; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
        {
            echo $i . ($i != 0 ? " " : "");
        }
    }
```

Or you use trim:

```
<?php
    $number=$_GET["number"];
    $output = "";
    if ($number < 0) {
        echo "The number should be at least zero!";
    } else {
        for($i=$number; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
        {
            $output .= $i . " ";
        }
    }
    echo trim($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$number=$_GET["number"];
if ($number < 0) {
    echo "The number should be at least zero!";
} else {
    $string = $number;
    for($i=$number-1; $i>=0; $i=$i-1)
    {
        $string .= " $i";

    }
}
echo $string;
?>
```